# Create a host directory using docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to create a directory on the host machine from within docker-compose?

For our project, we are using Docker/Docker Compose to create an environment for local development. One of the development requirements is creating a Database that can become rather large.

Due to some development machines (hosts) having a relatively small root partition, we are using the following to allow developers to specify the location of the data storage for the DB

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:11-3.2
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
    postgres:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: 'none'
        o: 'bind'
        device: ~/.docker/volumes/foo-postgres
```

This works well, but if the local directory `~/.docker/volumes/foo-postgres` does not exist (foo is replaced with our app name), an error is thrown.

Is there any way to tell docker-compose to create this directory if it doesn't exist so that developers can use the compose file without any manual setup?

Comment: If you delete every option under `volumes: { postgres: }`, then Compose will create a named volume in Docker-managed storage.  This should be fine for opaque data like a database, and can be faster on non-Linux hosts.  Is that a reasonable option for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze - no, that will end up creating the volume on the /root partition for Linux hosts, or wherever Docker engine is installed for Windows hosts (which under WSL 2 defaults to `c:`).

The size of the test database can end up being 50+ GB during development, and we need the ability to have that stored on a non-root drive.